# Socket.io client not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, sockets

I have created chat application using following

1. Rails
2. Rabbitmq
3. nodejs ( with amqplib/callback_api and socket.io )

I have following code in server side

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
var amqpConn = null;

var app = require('http').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.emit('news/1', msg.content.toString());
        // socket.disconnect()
});
```

client side

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://localhost:53597/socket.io/socket.io.js"  %>
<script>



var socket = io('http://localhost:53597', {reconnect: true});

  socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected');

    socket.on('news/1', function (msg) {
      console.log('inside coming');
      console.log(msg);
    });
  });

</script>
```

When I send message, message successfully pushed to queue and messages emitted to socket. The problem is I can get messages when only refresh page and messages are not deleted.

I can't understand what was wrong here ?

Comment: Are you only calling the `socket.emit` during the connection event, or do you have other calls to it not shown in your code? Otherwise, as written, it appears it would only have the single emit. Just to test, you could throw a `socket.emit` in a function triggered by `setInterval` on the server. Also, not sure about the messages not being deleted, I am not seeing anything in the code which is doing any deleting.

Comment: @barry: Are you only calling the socket.emit during the connection event ? Yes

Comment: My only requirement is to get the message from rabbitmq queue and emit message to listening sockets. I have trouble in socket.io client, but listening is working fine because I can show error messages in browser console when I stop nodejs server.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, as I was out at meetings. In anycase, as I said, if you only call `socket.emit(...)` the one time, it will only send one messasge. I am not a RabbitMQ user, but from a quick glance at the docs, it seems like the behavior you want would be achieved by making `socket.emit()` calls from inside the channel's `consume()` handler.

Comment: @barry Sorry for delay, your answer helped but I can understand after fixing the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I fixed my issue, the problem is I have placed emit function inside connection event, so that I can get data when only connection established​, connection is established when page load that is the reason I get data when only page load.

I have the following code for emit data

io.sockets.emit('news/1', msg.content.toString());